# Node: Download raw bytes of jpeg without piping output

Tags: image, node.js, buffer

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Retrieve raw data of an image (jpeg) from a URL given to me by an API
2. Pass the raw data or buffer to a function that uploads it to another server
3. NEVER PIPE THE IMAGE TO THE DISK

I've followed every example I can find (that doesn't pipe to disk), but still the content comes out corrupted. I have tried forcing various "accept-encodings" (gzip, deflate) but they basically resolve to the same data, just compressed.

I believe this has something to do with the response encoding rather than how I am asking for the data.

Here's the code so far:

```
var parsedUrl = require('url').parse(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
var params = {     
  hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
  path: parsedUrl.path,                                                                                                                                                                                        
}                  

return http.get(params, function(photo_res) {
  var photoData = '';
  res.setEncoding('binary');

  photo_res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    photoData += chunk;
  });              

  photo_res.on('end', function() {
    // DO STUFF TO UPLOAD IMAGE            
  });              

  photo_res.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Unable to download photo:', err);
    return done(err);
  });              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typographic error which may be causing Node to interpret your data stream with the incorrect type. Your error is in this line:

```
res.setEncoding('binary');
```

To avoid confusion you should keep the response variable named `res`, and since your data is in binary format, it might be better to keep it as a buffer.

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
  var photoData = [];

  res.setEncoding('binary');
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    photoData.push(chunk);
  });              

  res.on('end', function() {  
    var photo = Buffer.concat(photoData);       
  });              

  res.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Unable to download photo:', err);
  });              
});
```

In the example, I store all chunks of data into an array, then use `Buffer.concat()` to create a single buffer. It is better this way because you were originally appending your image's data onto a string, which may have cause the corruption.

Comment: This is within a nested request so I disambiguated them.
One retrieves the url of the image, the other gets the image data.

You are correct it was a typo, but no effect.

Comment: Have you attempted storing received data in a buffer instead of a string?

Comment: I did. Buffer.concat threw an error so I had to "new Buffer" first then concat, but shouldn't have made a difference.